# Call to a member function sum() on string

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have price column in my DB which I am trying to sum (after groupBy.) It is an integer. I am getting below error,

```
Call to a member function sum() on string
```

Code:

```
     $invoice =invoice::where('instructor_id', '=', $id)
        ->get()
        ->groupBy(function($date) {
            $result= Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('W,M,Y')->sum('price');
            return $result;
        })
```

Comment: You are calling `->sum()` on a formatted date string.

Comment: @Remul: Jave tried several things. How to fix it?

Comment: What is your desired result? should `$invoice` be the sum result?

Comment: @Remul: I need to return the sum of price for each week grouped.

Comment: Are you sure you want to `groupBy` after you have fetched the results? Seems like you should do this before the `->get()` function. `sum()` can then either be called on the collection or on the query builder instance. If you dont know what I'm talking about, read the Eloquent docs